# How to handle memoization with nil values with Sorbet?

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I have this method:

```rb
  def current_organization
    return @current_organization if defined?(@current_organization)

    subdomain = request.subdomain.to_s
    return @current_organization = nil if subdomain.blank?
    return @current_organization = nil if Allowable::DeniedSlugs.include?(subdomain)

    @current_organization = Organization.find_by(slug: subdomain)
  end
```

Because this file is `typed: strict`, I need to declare `@current_organization`, but this would mean that checking `defined?` would always be true. What is the correct pattern for handling `nil` for methods like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to declare `@current_organization` after checking `defined?` which can be done just above the `find_by` call

```
def current_organization
  return @current_organization if defined?(@current_organization)

  ...

  @current_organization = T.let(@current_organization, T.nilable(Organization))
  @current_organization = Organization.find_by(slug: subdomain)
end
```

Example on [sorbet.run](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20strict%0A%0Aclass%20Controller%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0A%20%20sig%20%7B%20returns%28T.nilable%28Organization%29%29%20%7D%0A%20%20def%20current_organization%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%40current_organization%20if%20defined%3F%28%40current_organization%29%0A%0A%20%20%20%20subdomain%20%3D%20request.subdomain.to_s%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%40current_organization%20%3D%20nil%20if%20subdomain.blank%3F%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%40current_organization%20%3D%20nil%20if%20Allowable%3A%3ADeniedSlugs.include%3F%28subdomain%29%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20adding%20below%20line%20will%20resolve%20the%20type%20error%0A%20%20%20%20%40current_organization%20%3D%20T.let%28%40current_organization%2C%20T.nilable%28Organization%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20%40current_organization%20%3D%20Organization.find_by%28slug%3A%20subdomain%29%0A%20%20end%0A%0A%20%20%23%20boilerplate%20to%20avoid%20other%20type%20issues%0A%20%20private%0A%20%20sig%20%7B%20returns%28Request%29%20%7D%0A%20%20def%20request%0A%20%20%20%20Request.new%0A%20%20end%0Aend%0A%0A%23%20more%20boiletplate%0Aclass%20Organization%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0A%20%20sig%20%7B%20params%28args%3A%20T.untyped%29.returns%28T.nilable%28Organization%29%29%20%7D%0A%20%20def%20self.find_by%28*args%29%0A%20%20%20%20Organization.new%0A%20%20end%0Aend%0A%0Aclass%20Allowable%0A%20%20DeniedSlugs%20%3D%20T.let%28%5B%5D%2C%20T%3A%3AArray%5BT.untyped%5D%29%0Aend%0A%0Aclass%20Request%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0A%20%20sig%20%7B%20returns%28T.untyped%29%20%7D%0A%20%20def%20subdomain%3B%20end%0Aend)